# What is the Javascript syntax for mapping this JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a React component pulling in JSON data via a "get" call. Here is the format of the retrieved data:

```
{
 "id": "5c114382-f9da-4dc2-8371-339659a1c8ec",
 "resourceId": "5c0a7671-f821-4131-9473-3fd1e80dbac1",
 "interface": "get_metrics",
 "inputs": {
   "stage": "TEST"
 },
 "outputs": {
   "metrics": {
     "devices_by_type": {
   "MX480": {
     "failed": 10,
     "total": 1235
   },
   "EX4200": {
     "failed": 3,
     "total": 1490
   },
   "ETX-203AX": {
     "failed": 123,
     "total": 9643
   },
   "MX960": {
     "failed": 52,
     "total": 1211
   },
   "GE114": {
     "failed": 1200,
     "total": 12530
   },
   "QFX5100": {
     "failed": 100,
     "total": 950
   },
   "MX240": {
     "failed": 10,
     "total": 245
   },
   "GE114Pro": {
     "failed": 0,
     "total": 125
   }
 },  
 "state": "successful",
 "reason": "",
 "progress": [],
 "providerData": {},
 "createdAt": "2018-12-12T17:21:06.174Z",
 "updatedAt": "2018-12-12T17:21:06.918Z",
 "resourceStateConstraints": {},
 "executionGroup": "lifecycle"
}
```

I have already successfully created a new Array of the devices_by_type names using the Object(keys) function. Now what I need to do is build two additional arrays of the failed and total NUMBERS only and I am not sure how to do this.

So, for example, my "failed" array would be:

const failedNumbers = [10, 3, 123, etc.] and likewise with the total numbers.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Map, Reduce Filter?

Comment: Those are objects not arrays

Comment: Right ... I know that the devices_by_type is an object and achieving what I need to do is going to probably require Object.keys, I just don't know the exact steps and syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Using reduce after fixing your missing end brackets

```js
const obj = {
  "id": "5c114382-f9da-4dc2-8371-339659a1c8ec",
  "resourceId": "5c0a7671-f821-4131-9473-3fd1e80dbac1",
  "interface": "get_metrics",
  "inputs": {
    "stage": "TEST"
  },
  "outputs": {
    "metrics": {
      "devices_by_type": {
        "MX480": {
          "failed": 10,
          "total": 1235
        },
        "EX4200": {
          "failed": 3,
          "total": 1490
        },
        "ETX-203AX": {
          "failed": 123,
          "total": 9643
        },
        "MX960": {
          "failed": 52,
          "total": 1211
        },
        "GE114": {
          "failed": 1200,
          "total": 12530
        },
        "QFX5100": {
          "failed": 100,
          "total": 950
        },
        "MX240": {
          "failed": 10,
          "total": 245
        },
        "GE114Pro": {
          "failed": 0,
          "total": 125
        }
      },
      "state": "successful",
      "reason": "",
      "progress": [],
      "providerData": {},
      "createdAt": "2018-12-12T17:21:06.174Z",
      "updatedAt": "2018-12-12T17:21:06.918Z",
      "resourceStateConstraints": {},
      "executionGroup": "lifecycle"
    }
  }
}

const devices = obj.outputs.metrics.devices_by_type;
const fails = Object.keys(devices).reduce(function(result, key) {
  result.push(devices[key].failed);
  return result;
}, []);
console.log(fails);
```